# Can't Import XML to FileMaker Pro 11

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker, importerror

First of all, excuse my ignorance as this issue is not my specialty: I have an XML file and I want to import into FileMaker. I have no XSL file, and I honestly do not know if necessary.
The problem is that as soon as I import, I get the error of FileMaker 717: "information XML / XSL insufficient to proceed with import / export".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You must have an XSL stylesheet to transform the XML source into
>   Filemaker's own XML grammar. The stylesheet cannot be generic, because
>   it must describe (a) the fields that Filemaker must import (or create,
>   if importing into a new table) and (:) the path to the data feeding
>   those fields.

From [FMForums](http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/73389-errors-importing-xml-xsd-no-xsl/)

If you're new to XSLT I suggest you check out the [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/). It has some handy reference pages as well.

Comment: @JackManey For a ground up tutorial w3schools isn't that bad. Eventually you'll want to go to the standard for definitive answer, but sometimes it's not worth mucking around in 40,000 lines of text for a simple transform.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is simple, just copy/paste it into a field and use a custom function like http://www.briandunning.com/cf/1/ to parse out the data and put it into fields.